# How to remove « from wordpress several section

Tags: wordpress

while writing wp_title(), next_post_link() and previous_post_link() a special character comes, i.e. "**«**". How to get rid of this character?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this article that will help you to craft a question that is likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**wp_title**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)

You can use something like `<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>` to remove the separator.

[**previous_post_link**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)

If you need to remove the `&laquo;`, you can just simply override it like this

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link'); ?>
```

[**next_post_link**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

If you need to remove the `&raquo;`, you can just simply override it like this

```
<?php next_post_link('%link'); ?>
```